# Usage of NOT IN and % together in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table `easy_drinks` with 2 columns `drink_name` VARCHAR & `second` VARCHAR. I wish to pull those records where the data in `second` column doesn't start by A, B or C

```
SELECT drink_name, second FROM easy_drinks WHERE second NOT IN ('A%', 'B%', 'C%');
```

I can get the desired result using the BETWEEN operator though ---

```
SELECT drink_name, second FROM easy_drinks WHERE NOT second BETWEEN 'A%' AND 'D%';
```

But I want to use it with the `NOT IN` operator

Comment: `substr(second,1,1) not in ('A','B','C')` but the engine can no longer use indexes. so this would be slowish.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would be easiest to use `REGEXP`

```
SELECT drink_name, second
FROM easy_drinks
WHERE second REGEXP ^[^ABC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can't use `In` with `Like` u can use this syntax

```
SELECT drink_name, second FROM easy_drinks WHERE second NOT Like 'A%' and second NOT Like 'B%' and second NOT Like 'C%';
```

Comment: I'm able to use like, but I wanted to specifically use NOT IN with the wildchar %

Comment: @Arvind sql cant use in or not in with like or not like.